# How to save a dataframe and an array to a new dataframe with new column names in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame **'test_raw'**, which has many columns. One of its column is **'datetime'**. I have used this data frame for machine learning. I have tested the model and got **'test_y_predicted'** which is an array of shape (5000,1).
**I want to make another data frame with these two column i.e. datetime in first column and test_y_predicted in another column and the column names should be 'Date Time and Count'**. Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': df['datetime'], 'Count': test_y_predicted})
```

**Update**

Your solution:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date time': test_raw.datetime,
                       'Count': test_y_predicted.flatten()})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it did solved 90% of the problem. The remaining 10%  I did.  With your code it gave the error: 'Data must be 1-dimensional'. Actually 'test_y_predicted' was a 2-D Array (5000,1). Therefore, I changed your code just a little. The working code was 'new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date time': test_raw.datetime, 'Count': test_y_predicted.flatten()}).   But really thanks.